# Debian Buster Can not set static IP

Tags: debian, networking, configuration

I have an NPI iMX6ULL ARM based single-board computer running Debian Buster.  It has 2 network ports listed by `ifconfig` as `eth0` and `eth1`

It seems to be ignoring my network configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo eth0 eth1

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.254
  netmask 255.255.255.0

iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

After booting the above configuration with `eth0` connected to a dhcp server, `ifconfig` reports:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.4.10.131  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 10.4.63.255
        inet6 fe80::d489:7cff:feec:e09e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:89:7c:ec:e0:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 478  bytes 42931 (41.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 29  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30  bytes 2883 (2.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=-28669<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        ether d6:89:7c:ec:e0:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Similarly, after booting the above configuration with `eth1` connected to a dhcp server, `ifconfig` reports:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d6:89:7c:ec:e0:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=-28605<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.4.11.126  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 10.4.63.255
        inet6 fe80::d489:7cff:feec:e09d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:89:7c:ec:e0:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1234  bytes 118390 (115.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 58  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 3547 (3.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If I do an `sudo ifdown eth1` it reports:

```
ifdown: interface eth1 not configured
```

and `sudo ifup eth1` it comes up:

```
debian@npi:~$ sudo ifup eth1
debian@npi:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.4.10.131  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 10.4.63.255
        inet6 fe80::d489:7cff:feec:e09e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:89:7c:ec:e0:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16846  bytes 1401257 (1.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 856  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 65  bytes 4551 (4.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=-28669<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether d6:89:7c:ec:e0:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What is controlling my network configuration on boot up.  How do I find out?

I did find a couple of Google hits that talked about issues with my MAC address but this happens to both interfaces.  I tried changing my MAC address as well, but nothing changed.

Comment: If you are running DHCP clients in your interfaces, they will win the war over static configurations. I also think ifup/ifdown are becoming deprecated, cannot remember the specifics.

Comment: How would I check to see if a DHCP client is running?  This is a stock Debian image based on the BeagleBone images.  Unfortunately, the manufacturer's support is lacking and I may need to move on to different hardware.

Comment: I feel your pain... I'm trying to sort wtfigo with my *"pocketbeagle"*. I don't think it's that your network settings are being ignored as it is that they need to work with the new `connman` way of doing things. [What is `connman`?](https://www.embedded-computing.com/articles/the-connman) I'm not even close to understanding that yet, but I do find that at least **some** of the legacy networking stuff still works.

Comment: The DHCP client is *probably* `dhclient`. It uses `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Comment: This is interesting - thought you might find it interesting also... apparently our Debian systems have both `connman` and `systemd-networkd` available. So perhaps either can be used??? What's the diff? - [here are some thoughts.](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/ethernet-network-(linux))

Comment: Thanks to Seamus.  You put me on the right track:  I found this page that shows several ways to solve this issue: https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/ethernet-network-(linux)  Of course I first tried removing connman but that had its own issues.  I recommend using connmanctl and setting a static IP as described in that article.

Comment: @cstrutton you can answer (and later accept) your own question, since it appears you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Seamus for pointing me in the right direction.  The key was that the image I was working with was based on the BeagleBone images.

The issue was `connman` taking control of the network ports before `networkd`.  On one unit, I was able to remove `connman` with `apt`.  After that, my configuration in `/etc/systemd/network/interfaces` was properly applied.

My research indicated that `connman` is the way of the future so I figured out how to configure that too.  This [page](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/ethernet-network-(linux)) gave lots of great info.  `connmanctl` can be used to set a static IP directly.

```
root@npi:~# connmanctl
connmanctl> config ethernet_00142d259a48_cable --ipv4 manual 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1
connmanctl> config ethernet_00142d259a48_cable --nameservers 8.8.8.8
connmanctl> exit
```

The hex string in the middle of the device name is the MAC address of the device.  manual specifies static IP and the numbers are the ipaddress, network mask and gateway (gateway is optional).

[This page also explains it well](http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Static_IP_Address).  Most documentation unfortunately is aimed at configuring wifi.  Most sites only mention static addressing in passing.

Hope this helps the next guy.